# not able to download nltk data folder by adding the dependency in requirement.txt file

Tags: python-2.7

-----> Downloading NLTK corpora...
          nltk.txt not found, not downloading any corpora

The dependency have been specified in the requirements.txt file but not downloading it

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .txt file -> nltk.txt 
in your root directory and mention all the corpora you want to download there.

Visit this link, it has all the answers.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk#keep-reading